# binary to decimal in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program which turns a binary number to decimal or decimal to binary. I have conditions, one of them is that I have to get numbers and number systems answers with the `gets` function. In my program, I changed char string to an integer value in order to use numbers. This is my little program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i,j,m, testnumber,realnumber,indx, total,k,x[10];
char numbersystem;
char number[10];

int main (){
    printf("Is your number \"decimal\" (d) or \"binary\" (b)) ");
    numbersystem = getchar();
    getchar();

    printf("Please Type your numbers");
    gets(number);

i=0;
realnumber=0;
while(number[i]!='\0'){
    realnumber = realnumber*10 + (number[i]-48);
    i++;
}

testnumber = i;
indx=1;

  if( numbersystem == 'b'){
      for(j=0; j<testnumber; j++){
         if (((number[j]-48)!=0) || ((number[j]-48)!=1)) {
             printf("\nYou cannot use diffrent number in Binary form\n");
             break;
         }else {
            for(k=testnumber-1; k>0; k--){
               if((number[k]-48)=='1'){
                for(m=0; m<j; m++){
                    indx = indx*number[m];
                }
                total = total + indx;
            }
          }
      }
   }
     printf("Number %d\n\n",total );
  }
}
```

My problem is I think here:

```
((number[j]-48)!=0) || ((number[j]-48)!=1))
```

I tried different ideas, then when I changed char string to integer,

```
(number[j]-48)
```

showed me a digit.

But when I tried to type binary numbers in my original program,  I used just "0" and "1" but I'm reaching this statement:

```
printf("\nYou cannot use diffrent number in Binary form\n");
             break;
```

I don't know what is the exact problem, so I need your help.

Comment: Looks like you need to do some basic debug. Have you checked what is in `number[j]`?

Comment: A sidenote, the line buffered input should be cleared manually before `printf("Please Type your numbers");` ie do `while (getchat()!='\n') continue;;` before it

Comment: the else condition should be `0 or 1` then the if condition should be `! (0 or 1)` which could be translated to `!0 and !1`

Comment: Who is telling you to use the `gets` function? That function is inherently dangerous. It was deprecated in the 1999 version of the C language, and removed altogether in C11.

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_! To subtract the code for `'0'` use `'0'` and no obscure integer constant! Better: compare directly with the character constants. Why do you subtrct there anyway? Is that for some obfuscation contest?

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
((number[j]-48)!=0) || ((number[j]-48)!=1))
```

will always evaluate to "true".   You probably want to combine the two tests with "and", rather than "or", like this:

```
((number[j]-48)!=0) && ((number[j]-48)!=1))
```

Comment: @Ren, this site can be a little harsh with beginner questions, and especially with English language learners.  You had a good question, but it was a little hard to understand.   I made a few edits to improve the grammar, so maybe the downvotes will stop...